# Android webview internet access limitation over data

Tags: android, webview

I'm currently using a webview to display local HTML content, but this content might refer to online images. What I need is to prevent this online data to be downloaded when the user is on 3G/4G. I just want the webview to access the internet on Wifi only.
I didn't find any way to do that... Is it possible ?

Comment: What is your min SDK level?

Comment: +1 for the sincere question..!

Answer (score 1):

To handle which url to be loaded and which not to be loaded : -

"Use WebView client with your web view and override this method shouldOverrideUrlLoading and in that don't call any url if its not one of your local url using the different states and if conditions
 based on your requirements in that method"

---

To decide either its on wi-fi or 3G/4G :-
Using the code below, you can detect whether phone is connected over wifi or data and can behave accordingly:

```
            public static boolean isDataEnabled(Context context)
            {
                return (isMobileDataEnabled(context) || isWifiEnabled(context));
            }


            public static boolean isMobileDataEnabled(Context context)
            {
                if(context == null)
                    return false;
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
                if (connectivityManager != null) {
                    networkInfo =
                        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
                }
                return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
            }

            public static boolean isWifiEnabled(Context context)
            {
                if(context == null)
                    return false;
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
                if (connectivityManager != null) {
                    networkInfo =
                        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                }
                return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
            }


    //Chceking user preference:

        public static boolean shouldUseOnlineServices(Context context)
        {
            if(context == null || isDataEnabled(context) == false)
                return false;

            SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            if(pref != null)
            {
                //String wifi = pref.getString("pref_camera_when_to_use_online_services","1");
                //boolean onlyOnWifi = (wifi.equals("0")== true) ? false:true;
                boolean onlyOnWifi = pref.getBoolean("pref_radio_wifi", false);
                if(onlyOnWifi == false)
                    return true;
                if(isWifiEnabled(context) == true)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            if(isWifiEnabled(context) == true)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: I know how to check the connectivity I just want to prevent my webview to access online content depending on the connectivity type

Comment: You can check the conncetivity and set a flag. Based on that flag, you can let the webview access online content. May be for example, you can have a sharedprefernce with options : 1. Only over wifi 2. Over wifi or data. Then based on user selection you want to do the online operation. I have edited to put that code also. Check it out.

Comment: @user1026605.. did u vote down my answer??

Comment: Forget the downvoter, +1 for nice piece of code written to determine the states.!!! Congrates.!!!  Now just add this in your answer **"Use WebView client with your web view and override this method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and in that don't call any url if its not one of your local url using the different states and if conditions based on your requirements in that method"** .. Simple is that.!!! @user1026605

Comment: @MKJParekh .. Thank you :). I was just wondering y it got downvoted as the answer is relevent in context of the question asked though it didnt suffice the need of person who asked the question..

Comment: @MKJParekh Thx that was what I am looking for. Please make it as an answer so I can validate it. Sorry but the other answer about how to test connectivity wasn't relevant to my question ;)

Comment: @Sushil please edit your answer with the bold line written in above comment and then user1026605 you can check this answer only..! Happy Coding.!

Comment: @MKJParekh. I have edited my answer and have kept your correct answer over top in bold.

Comment: In fact shouldOverrideUrlLoading() doesn't work for images. It will only detect youtube links for exemple but not images...

Comment: I just fond how to do it... Don't know I missed it before.
webview.setBlockNetworkImage(boolean)
Thanks for your help

Comment: Good work @user1026605 So now you need both the things to get your work done 1) using webview client 2) webview setting to block network